# how to set static files directory in django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings, django-static

I am trying to get an existing django app up and running, but the css or any other static files are not showing up.  I get the error:

```
"GET /static/css/mycss.css HTTP/1.1" 404 50
```

In the settings the following values are used:

```
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'assets'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),
)
```

The app contains a directory called "static".  It is in the current directory structure:

> my-django-project > my-django-project > static > css > mycss.css

When I hit the home url via localhost, I get the above 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post your webserver configuration as well. Django usually doesn't serve static files at all, you're supposed to configure your webserver to handle those requests directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `collectstatic` command to collect the static files in your apps to the `STATIC_ROOT`.

The command can be run like this:

```
python managy.py collectstatic
```

More information about static files can be found in the [django documentation on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

Comment: i collected all the static files, I am still getting the 404s

Comment: ok, was a new directory `my-django-project > static` created that contains the static files from your app ?

Comment: I see. Updated my answer with information about where static files are collected (´STATIC_ROOT` and not `STATICFILES_DIR`).

Comment: Are you using the development server (i.e. `./manage.py runserver`) or some other webserver?

Comment: Check that some static file from the app actually exists in the `assets` dir (i.e. `assets/css/mycss.css`) and check that the `django.contrib.staticfiles` are in your `INSTALLED_APPS` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).